# Kriterien zum Downvoten von Fragen

Tags: discussion

Ich bin relativ neu hier und trotz Suche ist es mir nicht gelungen, eine Antwort auf die Frage oben zu finden.

Ich habe allerdings manchmal das Gefühl, dass Fragen, die durchaus legitim sind, "downvotet" werden. Wenn jemanden ein Thema nicht interessiert, ist er/sie frei sich zu enthalten, oder sehe ich das falsch?

Das alte Motto "es gibt keine dummen Fragen" ist vielleicht zu großzügig, aber ein gewisses kooperatives Wohlwollen sollte schon herrschen.

Könnte mich jemand, der hier mehr Erfahrung hat, kurz aufklären?

Ergänzend zum gestrigen Posting (und nein, ich beziehe mich nicht auf meine Fragen im Forum): Es gibt mittlerweile zig unbeantwortete Fragen mit einer Reihe von "downvotes". Ich finde es schade, denn -im Gegensatz zu meinem anfänglichen Eindruck- ich habe das Gefühl, dass die Seite mittlerweile immer mehr die jetzige Welle der gesellschaftlichen Gehässigkeit hinter vorgehaltener Hand widerspiegelt, anstatt ein Ort für konstruktive Diskussionen zu sein.

Comment: es wäre hilfreich wenn angesprochene Postings auch verlinkt werden, denn wir sind faul, bzw nicht erwähnt werden, denn wir sind leicht abzulenken.

Comment: Was bedeutet "denn wir sind faul, bzw nicht erwähnt werden, denn wir sind leicht abzulenken"?

Comment: das heißt das ich den Link nicht suchen werde, mir der bezug dazu fehlt, und dass mich überhaupt der ganze Absatz am Ende eher stört

Comment: Dein gutes Recht...

Comment: Neben [einigen Meta Posts von mir](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3Ame+downvote)  gibt es zu diesem Thema auch eine "offizielle" Richtlinie: [Privileges/vote down](https://german.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-down)

Comment: Verstehe. Da steht aber auch "Downvoting should be reserved for extreme cases". Daher steht ein User evtl. ziemlich harmlos da, wenn keine Erklärungen fürs Downvoten angegeben werden, was nicht selten geschieht...

Comment: Gründe für einen Downvote sind immer sehr subjektiv. Darüber kann man sicherlich diskutieren. Dennoch denke ich, dass [dieser meta-Post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121350/ive-just-been-downvoted-how-should-i-react#answer-121351) das ganze gut zusammenfasst und erklärt. Downgevotete Fragen ohne einzige Antwort sind hier (gse) so gut wie immer "geschlossen" - meist wegen [off-tpoic](https://german.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) -, können also auch gar nicht mehr beantwortet werden. Erzeugen diese geschlossenen Fragen evtl bei dir den Eindruck?

Comment: Ich bin natürlich nicht ständig am Rechner, aber ich beobachte schon mal, dass Fragen mit Downvotes ohne Antworten vorkommen. Ob die dann geschlossen werden, verfolge ich nicht aktiv. Es gibt auch etliche Fälle von Downvotes ohne Begründung seitens der "Downvotenden" sozusagen, was IMHO weder reif noch konstruktiv ist.

Answer (score 3):

Wenn man auf `Ask Question` klickt, so stehen rechts im Kasten die folgenden 2 Sätze:

> If you are asking for a translation, meaning, or similar: Tell us why a dictionary did not help you.
>
> We do not translate or proofread texts. Ask about a single, specific problem instead.

In meiner Wahrnehmung sammeln gerade Fragen, die dagegen "verstoßen" sehr schnell Downvotes und Closevotes und ich finde es dort auch vertretbar ein Minus zu vergeben. Für den Fall, dass der Nutzer seinen Post editiert und erklärt, warum das Wörterbuch nicht weiterhilft, kann das Minus dann auch entsprechend in ein Plus verwandelt werden.

Wie das in der Praxis konkret aussieht - daran scheiden sich die Geister:

[is-haben-always-accusative-or-sometimes-dative](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/54765/is-haben-always-accusative-or-sometimes-dative)
Diese Frage hat insgesamt ganze 4 Downvotes gesammelt. Meiner Meinung nach beruht sie auf einfach nur auf einem Missverständnis. Wenn man Gitarren für ein Dativobjekt hält (und die declension table keinen Aufschluss darüber gibt, weil alle Pluralformen von Gitarre nunmal Gitarren sind), so kann man schonmal durcheinander kommen.

[Dem Bus and fahren in a sentence](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/41778/dem-bus-and-fahren-in-a-sentence)
Diese Frage hat 3 Downvotes erhalten. Ich finde diese Frage höchst unverständlich. Der Fragesteller scheint sich hier kaum bis keine Mühe gegeben zu haben. Hier finde ich die Downvotes gerechtfertigt.

Am Ende muss jeder für sich selbst entscheiden. Eine Begründung ist auf jeden Fall sinnvoll, damit der Nutzer weiß, wie er die Frage verbessern kann. Auch sollte man bei einem Downvote im Hinterkopf behalten, es nach einem Edit ggf. in ein Upvote zu verwandeln, wenn man der Meinung ist, auf die Kritik wurde genügend eingegangen.

An dieser Stelle möchte ich auch nochmal auf diesen Kommentar unter einer anderen Frage eingehen:

> Wenn ein Muttersprachler nicht weiß, dass "liegen" mit dem Dativ gebildet wird, ist das schon mal eine schlechte und traurige Frage. Insofern müsste die Frage downvotet (sic!) werden.

Unwissenheit ist m.M.n. niemals ein Grund zu downvoten. Ob Muttersprachler oder nicht, es gilt getreu der Sesamstraße "wer nicht fragt bleibt dumm". Desweiteren zeigt die Antwort von Björn, dass liegen auch mit dem Akkusativ gebildet werden kann.

Abschließend lässt sich sagen: **Es empfiehlt sich vor dem Downvoten einer Frage diese noch einmal aufmerksam zu lesen und sich in die Situation des anderen hereinzuversetzen. Oft sind Dinge, die für einen selbst klar sind, für andere Leute nicht klar.**

Comment: Du bist im falschen Film! Ich habe den Fragenden nicht downvotet! Das tue ich nie! Ich habe ihm erklärt, wie "liegen" funktioniert, und dafür von ihm und 2 anderen erstmal 2 Downvotes gekriegt (höchstwahrscheinlich von dir, denn ich kenne dich mittlerweile ziemlich gut und traue dir einiges zu). Nochmal (hatte es schon vor ein paar Wochen geschrieben): Gehe deinen Weg! Ich werde dich künftig glatt ignorieren egal, worum es geht!).

Comment: 1) Was ist ihr Problem, dass sie noch jedesmal so angehen müssen? 2) Ich habe nie behauptet, sie hätten irgendwas downgevotet. 3) Sie sind derjenige, der, wenn er denkt, Leute könnten ihn downgevotet haben, aus "Rache" willkürlich downvotes zurückwirft. 4) In meinem Post steht nicht einmal "musste", keine Ahnung wovon sie sprechen.